# HTML/JavaScript, how to scroll a page to a certain tag value?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page with over a hundred HTML5 audio tags, like this :

```
<audio controls=""> <source src="NameOfFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</source></audio>

<audio controls=""> <source src="NameOfFile2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</source></audio>

<audio controls=""> <source src="NameOfFile3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</source></audio>
```

Is there a way I can code it so when a link or button is clicked, it scrolls to the place in the page where that .mp3 file is? Basically scroll to a certain "source src" value?

I know I can do it with a div like this :

```
 <a href="#Test">scroll to test</a>


  <div id="Test">

...
```

but what about "source scr" value like mentioned? Really noob at HTML I mostly work with powershell scripting. Much appreciated.

Comment: java tag is for what ?

Comment: Just give the <source> elements ids.

Comment: @MisterJojo Java tag is for in case javascript can do it better than HTML.

Comment: @MrLister so without an ID it's not possible right? I would've liked to not have to add IDs to nearly 200 source elements but I guess that will have to do

Comment: ? I don't see the point of this provocation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible, however, you still have to link your buttons/anchor tags to each individual `audio` element so that you know that when you click `AudioFileX` it will scroll to the appropriate position.

In the example below, I used `data-*` attributes that hold values related to the `src` attribute of each `audio` element.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', handleAudioAnchorClicks)

function handleAudioAnchorClicks() {
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
  const allAudioElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio'))

  for (let i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    const button = allButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', handleOnClick)
  }

  function handleOnClick(event) {
    const target = event.target
    const audioId = target.getAttribute('data-audio-name')
    const audioElement = allAudioElements.find(el => {
      const source = el.querySelector('source').getAttribute('src')
      return source.includes(audioId)
    })
    const audioElementRect = audioElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    const scrollToPosition = audioElementRect.top
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollToPosition)
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button type="buton" data-audio-name="NameOfFile">NameOfFile</button>
<button type="buton" data-audio-name="NameOfFile2">NameOfFile2</button>
<button type="buton" data-audio-name="NameOfFile3">NameOfFile3</button>
<hr />
<div>
  <p>NameOfFile.mp3</p>
  <audio controls="">
    <source src="NameOfFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
  </audio>
</div>
<div>
  <p>NameOfFile2.mp3</p>
  <audio controls="">
    <source src="NameOfFile2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
  </audio>
</div>
<div>
  <p>NameOfFile3.mp3</p>
  <audio controls="">
    <source src="NameOfFile3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
  </audio>
</div>
```

You could, of course, generate those buttons dynamically with appropriate attributes that link to your `audio` elements or select all buttons/anchors from the page and assign `data-*` attributes with appropriate values so that you can link them to `audio` elements.

The tricky part would be to know which buttons belong to which audio elements - if they are in the same order then the following should work:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', handleAudioAnchorClicks)

function handleAudioAnchorClicks() {
  const allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button')
  const allAudioElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('audio'))
  
  // assign `data-audio-name` attributes to each button,
  // assuming they are in the same order as the `audio` elements
  for (let i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    const button = allButtons[i]
    const audioElement = allAudioElements[i]
    const src = audioElement.querySelector('source').getAttribute('src')
    const [name, ext] = src.split('.')
    button.setAttribute('data-audio-name', name) 
    button.addEventListener('click', handleOnClick)
  }

  function handleOnClick(event) {
    const target = event.target
    const audioId = target.getAttribute('data-audio-name')
    const audioElement = allAudioElements.find(el => {
      const source = el.querySelector('source').getAttribute('src')
      return source.includes(audioId)
    })
    const audioElementRect = audioElement.getBoundingClientRect()
    const scrollToPosition = audioElementRect.top
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollToPosition)
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<button type="buton">NameOfFile</button>
<button type="buton">NameOfFile2</button>
<button type="buton">NameOfFile3</button>
<hr />
<div>
  <p>NameOfFile.mp3</p>
  <audio controls="">
    <source src="NameOfFile.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
  </audio>
</div>
<div>
  <p>NameOfFile2.mp3</p>
  <audio controls="">
    <source src="NameOfFile2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
  </audio>
</div>
<div>
  <p>NameOfFile3.mp3</p>
  <audio controls="">
    <source src="NameOfFile3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
      Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </source>
  </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: Really nice answer, I will adapt it to my page, much much appreciated.

Comment: @Rakha see the edit if you want to dynamically assign `data-*` attributes to each button/anchor if the button/anchors are in the same order as the `audio` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mr Lister for the heads up in comments.

Just have to add an ID for each tags for example :

```
<audio id="Test" controls="">
<source src="Test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">Your browser does
not support the audio element.
</source></audio>
```

Then simply create a link that scrolls to that ID :

```
<a href="#test">Scroll to Test ID</a>
```

Comment: Note that this example uses `Test` for the id and `#test` for the link, which is not the same.